# Categorised Multiple File uploads within a page in Drupal 7

Tags: views, nodes, files

I have a situation where I have to upload multiple files within categories. This can be explained by the following picture.[image: Categorised Multiple File uploads within a page in Drupal 7]

As you can see I need to upload multiple files, but also need to categorize them. Each category has different files and even though below picture shows the same name of the files, they are not shared. How can I do it in Drupal 7. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all of these attached to one node and the categories need to be dynamic, I'd use [field collections](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) where each category is a field collection item which has a title field and a multi value file field.

Comment: Thank you, but any way I can ouput it :( I don't know how to output it through a view.